# Is this a LEGO part? rectangular base with sides, and a bar extending from the middle

Tags: part-identification, bionicle

I distinctly remember separating this part from some Bionicle parts. But is it a original LEGO part? There are no part numbers or other marks on this piece - except for a "2" (seems to be the right font for a LEGO piece - injecting mold production line number?). No LEGO logo.

I have searched the BrickLink catalogue, but without any luck. Thank you for any help

[image: rectangular base with sides, and a bar extending from the middle]

[image: rectangular base with sides, and a bar extending from the middle]

Comment: I also have a tub of them separated out from clone-piece winnowing. I'm fairly sure we're out of luck regarding them being Lego. I wonder if they're for a race track, where the big part clips on and the other part points up to attach railings.

Comment: Yes, I think you might be right. I don't really see how this part would fit into the lego system... :-)

Answer (score 24):

It's an accessory to the LEGO BIONICLE Bohrok and Bohrok-Kal sets, which can be used to hang the Bohrok sets in the product canister, which doubles as their cocoon/nest.

[image: Bohrok hanging in canister]

It attaches to a clip inside the lid and clips onto the Bohrok's back-side, as shown in the [instructions](https://www.lego.com/service/buildinginstructions/8578):

[image: Instructions about clip]

It appears it is not considered a "piece" per-se (which would have a part number and be included in the part count), but you can find the listing [on BrickLink here](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?G=x349). Yours appears to be blue, like [Gahlok-Kal's](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8578-1) canister lid.

Comment: You beat me by 6 minutes! I posted almost the same answer so I deleted mine. This is definitely the part in question.

Comment: Amazing! I guess it's obvious I've never opened a new Bionicle canister.